# form.serializeArray() - How to use it for non-input tags which do not accept name attribute like label, td

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, serialization

I have a dynamically generated table. This table is generated from the JSON string. Now when the table is generated and displayed on the page, The users can edit it and save them again. Once they click on Save, I want to generate the JSON back from the html (with edited data) and send it to server using ajax.

My problem is, the table which is dynamically generated is having just tr td and label elements as text and not having any `<input>` tag elements. Since i cann't add any "name" attribute on label, td I am getting empty string when calling form.serializeArray().

How can i serialize the form which have just "non-input" tag elements. Thanks for your help !!
-Manish

Comment: You'll have to do it manually. Get the values/text and whatever identifies your elements, and create a data object that is sent with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating the result JSON object manually.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var result = {};
    $.each($('form label'), function (index, item) {
        result[index] = $(item).text();
    });
    console.log(result);
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    return false;
});
```

Please see the below fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/fUqt6/)

Answer (score 0):

`serializeArray()` return an array of object(s). You could just push in it your relevant data:

```
var arrDatas = $("form").serializeArray();
arrDatas.push({
    name: 'nameOfLabel',
    value: 'value to add'
});
```